# Android Java Notification To Alarm

Tags: java, android, notifications, fragment, alarm

How do I rebuilt my Notification to get a 'Notification Alarm'
I tried varois things but nothing worked, I am really frustated so I finally ask here.

Main Activity:

```
public void sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent01 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent01 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent01, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder01 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent01)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(gamesJuliToStringArray[1])
            .setContentText("Spiel ist bereit")
            .setSubText("click");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_01, builder01.build());
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Condition in my Fragment:

```
    if (!notification062 && !buttonColor02.equals("red02")) {
        activity.sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01();
    }
```

Again I get Notifications if the conditions happens, but only inside of my application.
Need help for rebuilding this into and alarm notification

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223) you can see an example of the AlarmManager being used to schedule a notification for a later time, given a specific delay.